# tk tablelist - how to make a particular row as default selection

Tags: tcl

```
tablelist::tablelist .t -columns { 0 TYPE }  -width 248 -height 15 

set total_row [.t size]
```

The total rows are 25.

I want to make 20th row selected by default. How to make row 20th as default selection and view to user as default.

thanks,
Nagaraj.

Comment: Did you try with the *selection* command?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. Below command did the work.

set my_row 20

.t seecell $my_row,0

.t selection set  $my_row